# Is the use of the word 'in' at the end of this sentence incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

It is never too late to change the direction your life is headed in.

Comment: Context please.

Comment: Or "It is never to late to change the direction in which your life is headed."

Comment: @Kristina: We're playing way past that. Please see the question and answer this is a duplicate of.

Comment: @Robusto, yup.  However, the answer is deleted and the dup is a link.  In my judgement, it's not a bad idea to include it as a comment for our new member...though I also voted to close the question as a dup. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks grammatical to me, but it is rather cumbersome. I'd just say

> It is never too late to change your life's direction

*Your life's direction* means *the way your life is headed* already.